# Print out in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, echo

Is it possible to print out text in PHP while a for loop is running? I mean normally it runs the whole loop until the end and then you can see all the text. But I need the text every time when the echo is there in the for loop, not after the whole loop. Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[void flush (void)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)**
>   Flushes the write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push current output all the way to the browser with a few caveats. [(more)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php)

There are quite a few caveats. Make sure to read the linked page and comment section if you encounter any problems. For example:

> - Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those browsers to display the page.
> - Keep in mind that Internet Explorer and Safari have a 1k buffer before incremental rendering kicks in, so you'll want to output some padding as well.